# Accessing request object along with response in http outbound gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am using http oubound gateway to make http requests using the similar configuration as below:

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway id="httpOutboundGateway" request-channel="requestChannel"
    url="http://www.google.com" http-method="GET" reply-channel="responseChannel"
    expected-response-type="java.lang.String" charset="UTF-8" reply-timeout="5000"
    message-converters="" >
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

1. How to access the request object (request message pushed into request channel) when processing the response?
2. Is there a way to see the final url/request that it is executing after replacing the request parameters in the url?

Answer (score 0):

1. Since it is an `outbound-gateway` and there is a `request-channel`, you can simply save the inbound `Message` (or its `payload`) to the `headers`. Having that in headers you can get access to it from the `responseChannel` down-flow.
2. To see the real `URL` you should switch on `DEBUG` for the `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate`, which does this:

   ```
   private void logResponseStatus(HttpMethod method, URI url, ClientHttpResponse response) {
       if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
           try {
               logger.debug(method.name() + " request for \"" + url + "\" resulted in " +
                       response.getStatusCode() + " (" + response.getStatusText() + ")");
           }
           catch (IOException e) {
               // ignore
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: You can use a `<header-enricher/>` to save the payload in a header.